# Shifting text out of tabular cell

Tags: tables, indentation

Is there a simple and robust way to achieve what is illustrated by the two black arrows below, i.e., shifting the title in a right-aligned column right by a fixed amount.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{3.5cm}@{}}
Coltitle1 & Coltitle2 \tabularnewline
AB & 5 \tabularnewline
A & 11 \tabularnewline
AC & 10 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{3.5cm}@{}}
Coltitle1 & LongColtitle2 \tabularnewline
AB & 5 \tabularnewline
A & 11 \tabularnewline
AC & 10 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to avoid bad box(es)-warnings.  Also, I would prefer (=not absolutely necessary) if the right end of the table would stay where it is, i.e., directly adjacent to the numbers. I.e.,

```
Coltitl|e2         instead of       Coltitle2|
      5|                                  5  |
     10|                                 10  |
    ...|                                  ...|
```

where  `|` marks the right end of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say

```
\makebox[\dimexpr(\width-2em)][l]{LongColTitle2}
```

However, the table width will not take into account the shift. That may be done with a suitable table preamble such as

```
\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{3.5cm}@{\hspace{2em}}}
```

Comment: @Frank: `\dimexpr` allows you to subtract 2em from the `\width`. I normally write it as `\dimexpr\width-2em\relax`.